# How do you edit the favorites list on Lion finder?

Tags: macos, finder

Dragging in and out doesn't seem to be working for me, but I can see the ones I dragged in there before I upgraded:

[image: favorites list]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should still be able to drag items on to the sidebar. To remove them either right/command(⌘)-click and select *Remove from Sidebar* or drag while holding ⌘.

Comment: weird: dragging in wasn't working before, but it is now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can drag folders out anymore (to prevent accidental deletions), but if you right click you should have a "remove from sidebar" item in the context menu.

Answer (score 1):

Command/drag works for me - as does the right click.